# For loops and range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm a beginner to programming and Python and I'd like to clarify a simple question on for loops.

```
def check(number):
  for number in range(0,10):
        if number/2*2==number:
            print "Even nos:", (number)

        else:
            print "Odd nos:", (number)
check(6)
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this result?

```
Even nos: 0
Odd nos: 1
Even nos: 2
Odd nos: 3
Even nos: 4
Odd nos: 5
Even nos: 6
Odd nos: 7
Even nos: 8
Odd nos: 9
```

I actually want to check if number 6 is even.. Unless what number is inside the bracket doesn't really matter since this piece of code will check the entire range, 0 to 10, for even numbers? Sorry pretty confused about this right now :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you just want to know if `check(6) == True`?

Comment: What do you think would happen if you redefine a variable?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your `number/2*2==number` conditional does not need the `for` loop around it.

Comment: Ah thanks everyone for your answers! I now understand where I went wrong! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Unless what number is inside the bracket doesn't really matter since this piece of code will check the entire range, 0 to 10, for even numbers?

Bingo. You pass in `number` but then your loop ignores what was passed in and changes `number` according to the loop definition, which loops over the range 0-9.

You probably wanted something like:

```
def check(number):
    print number % 2 == 0
```

Or:

```
def check(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print "Even no: ", number
    else:
        print "Odd no: ", number
```

Note the use of the modulo (%) operator, which ["yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second."](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
def check(number):
  for number in range(0,10):
```

On the first line of your function, you redefine your argument, and thus don't have access to it anymore. Your function runs always the same way, no matter what you give it.

I think what you want to do is:

```
def check(number):
     if number/2*2==number:
        print "Even nos:", (number)
     else:
        print "Odd nos:", (number)
```

and then

```
check(6)
```

or

```
for number in range(0,10):check(number)
```

And to conclude, a better way to check the evenness of a number is `number%2==0` which means *"does it remains nothing when I divide this number by 2"*

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus (%) to check for even/oddness:

```
In [20]: def isodd(number):
    return bool(number%2)
   ....: 

In [21]: isodd(6)
Out[21]: False
```

Problem avoided.

But as @devnull suggests, you're redefining what the passed parameter "number" is. Your code seems to be trying to do two things.